# How to use HttpClient to send content into req.body of GET request in angular?

Tags: angular, request, httpclient

how to send data to req.body  while requesting through a HttpClient.get()

Comment: Manideep Mani: If you want to add additional information to your question then edit **your question**. If you want to comment on a particular answer then use the **comment** feature. I just rejected your edit to my answer because it wasn't answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you cannot use HttpClient get to send a body. The only way is to use query.

```
const someObject = {example object};
http.get(url + '/?data='+ encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(someObject)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

The [behaviour of a GET request with a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) is undefined by the specification, and the APIs provided to client-side JS for making HTTP requests (`fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`) do not support associating a request body with a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

A get request can't have a body, you should use post or put https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp